# Putting if statement in Ruby create

Tags: ruby, if-statement, class-method

```
Example.create(
  attribute1 = "asdf",
  attribute2 = "asdf2",
  attribute3 = "and 20 more attributes"
)
```

But how do I conveniently make `variable2 = "qwer"` if `random_thing == "zxcv"`, without having to have two (nearly) identical create methods inside an if/else?

Comment: Used to the convenience of Python? Ruby does this with *kwargs* like `attribute1: ..., attribute2: ...` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a block to the [create](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) method, which you can you use to conditionally "overwrite" `attribute2`:

```rb
Example.create(attribute1: "asdf",
               attribute2: "asdf2",
               attribute3: "and 20 more attributes") do |e|
  e.attribute2 = "qwer" if random_thing == "zxcv"
end
```

Edit: I have found a more beautiful and elegant solution. So I replaced the initial approach with the version above.

Comment: It's worth noting that `if` can appear in an argument position, it's just another expression that evaluates to whatever branch fired.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps by using a [ternary operator](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if):

```
Example.create(
  attribute1 = "asdf",
  attribute2 = random_thing == "zxcv" ? "qwer" : "asdf2",
  attribute3 = "and 20 more attributes"
)
```

Or simplified:

```
Example.create("asdf", random_thing == "zxcv" ? "qwer" : "asdf2", "and 20 more attributes")
```

Comment: I appreciate that ty. I'm going to go with the block for scalability, since "for readability it is recommended that the ternary if is only used for simple conditionals." as per the docs

Answer (score 1):

If your input parameters are a hash, you can just pass

```
Example.create(attributes)
```

Rails automatically create instance with provided params

If there are any values in the parameters that you want to avoid when creating the record, use the following

```
Example.create(attributes.except(:parameter_to_except)
```